# Get each button or anchor attributes as json string on click event no jQuery

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the attribute values as json string on each button and anchor element on a click event.

Like this.

```
<a href="test.html" div="mydiv" class="myclass" layer="mylayer"></a>
<button type="button" name="button" value="btnValue" id="btn"></button>

    {
        "attributes": {
             "href": "test.html",
             "div": "mydiv",
             "class": "myclass",
             "layer": "mylayer"
        }
    }

{
    "attributes": {
        "type": "button",
        "name": "button",
        "value": "btnValue",
        "id": "btn"
    }
}
```

This is my code js code

```
var attr = document.querySelectorAll('button, a');
for (var i = 0;i < attr.length;i++){
    attr[i].addEventListener('click',function(){
        console.log(attr);
      });
}
```

Can anyone help me with this how can i achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var myjson=[];

$("a,button").click(function(){
  $.each(this.attributes, function() {
   if(this.specified) {
     var a = {
      "name":this.name,
      "value":this.value
     }
     myjson.push(a);

    }
  });
  console.log(myjson);
})
```

https://jsfiddle.net/fx3zrsjg/1/

Comment: Yes, I believe so

Answer (score 0):

The HTML provided by the OP was bad:

- `<a>`nchor is missing the end tag `</a>`
- Non-standard attributes `[div]` and `[layer]` do not exist. If in need of a custom attribute name, the valid way to do so is by prefixing custom names with: **[`data-`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)**.

The demo below will:

- collect all DOM elements/tags matching a given selector into a NodeList
- register DOM elements to the click event
- assign a unique #id to any tag lacking an #id
- assign `data-text` attribute to all tags that contain text and assign its value to the text content.
- any tag belonging to NodeList that gets clicked will:

  - create an object with the same name as the tag's #id
  - populate object with its attributes as key/value pairs.
  - add the object to Object `AttrList`

Full line-by-line description is commented in demo

```js
const API = attr => ({
  /** getAttr(event)
  @Params: event[Object]...: default value for all event handlers
           selector[String]: DOM target(s)
  //A - Reference the clicked tag
  //B - if clicked tag has selector...
  //C - ...and if it didn't have an #id...
  //D - ...assign clicked tag an #id by concating its tagName and
        a modified number derived from the current timestamp...
  //E - ...and if clicked has any text...
  //F - ...assign [data-text] to it with the value of its text
  //G - Add an object to ATTRList Object with the computed name of 
        clicked.id
  //H - Collect all of clicked attribute names into an array of
        strings by using .getAttributeNames() method.
        Iterate through the array with a for...of loop to get
        current attribute name
  //I - Assign the current name as a property of
        ATTRList[clicked.id] as well as the current attribute
        value 
 */
  getAttr: event => {
    const clicked = event.target; //A

    if (clicked.matches(attr.selector)) { //B
      if (!clicked.hasAttribute('id')) { //C
        clicked.id = clicked.tagName + Math.floor(performance.now()) + ""; //D
      }
      if (clicked.textContent.length > 0) { //E
        clicked.dataset.text = clicked.textContent; //F
      }
      attr.ATTRList[clicked.id] = {}; //G
      for (let name of clicked.getAttributeNames()) { //H
        attr.ATTRList[clicked.id][name] = clicked.getAttribute(name); //I
      }
      console.log(attr.ATTRList);
    }
    return false;
  },

  /** getNodes()
  @Params: selector[String]: DOM target(s) 
  // - for each iteration register click event to current node
  */
  getNodes: () => {
    for (let node of attr.NodeList) {
      node.onclick = attr.getAttr; //B
    }
  }
});

const attributes = selector => {
  let attr = {
    selector,
    NodeList: document.querySelectorAll(selector), //A
    ATTRList: {}
  };
  return Object.assign(attr, API(attr));
};

const A = attributes('.clk');
A.getNodes();
```

```html
<a href="#/" name='clk0' class="clk lnk" data-layer=".layer">Click Link</a>
<button id='clk1' name='clk1' class='clk btn' type="button" value="0">Click Button</button>
```