# Get each button or anchor attributes as json string on click event only

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get all the attribute values as json string on each button and anchor element on a click event.

Like this.

```
<a href="test.html" div="mydiv" class="myclass" layer="mylayer"></a>
 <button type="button" name="button" value="btnValue" id="btn"></button>

        {
            "attributes": {
                 "href": "test.html",
                 "div": "mydiv",
                 "class": "myclass",
                 "layer": "mylayer"
            }
        }

    {
        "attributes": {
            "type": "button",
            "name": "button",
            "value": "btnValue",
            "id": "btn"
        }
    }
```

This is  code js code

```
var elements = document.querySelectorAll('button, a');
var elementAttributes = [];
elements.forEach(function(el){
  var attrs = {attributes:{}};
   for(var i=0; i<el.attributes.length; i++) {
     attrs.attributes[el.attributes[i].name] = el.attributes[i].value;
   }
  elementAttributes.push(attrs);
});

console.log(JSON.stringify(elementAttributes));
```

This is working fine but only issue is i want this code to be work only on click event.

Can anyone help me here how can i set a click event on each button and anchor tag.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you on another account asking the same question that you asked 4 hours ago? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56465261/get-each-button-or-anchor-attributes-as-json-string-on-click-event-no-jquery

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit rough but it will pull the **written** attributes rather than the vast collection found under `HTMLElement.attributes`

```js
const getAttributes = (el) => {
  let val = el.outerHTML;
  val = val.slice(val.indexOf(' ')+1, val.indexOf('>'))
           .split(' ')
           .reduce((a,v) => {
              const [key, value] = v.split('=');
              a.attributes[key] = value.replace("\"", '').replace("\"", ''); // Need a regex here.
              return a;
            }, {"attributes" : {}});
  return val;
}

document.addEventListener('click', (event) => {
  //console.log (event.target.attributes);
  if(event.target.matches('a, div, button')) {
    console.log(getAttributes(event.target));
  }
});
```

```html
<a href="#" div="mydiv" class="myclass" layer="mylayer">Test</a>
<button type="button" name="button" value="btnValue" id="btn">Test</button>
```